# How do I get a grid in a XAML code page in Xamarin on VS

Tags: xml

I am trying to get the ZxingScanner View to be a panel right across the whole screen.

I have tried all possibilities of the grid values in the  to no availail.

Here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                        x:Class="ZXingSample.PartialScreenScanning"
                        xmlns:zxing="clr-namespace:ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms;assembly=ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms"
                        Title="Scan Page">

            <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions >
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <BoxView Grid.Row ="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
         <zxing:ZXingScannerView x:Name="_scanView" OnScanResult="Handle_OnScanResult" IsScanning="true"
                              WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300"  />
        <zxing:ZXingDefaultOverlay/>
        <BoxView/>
                
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Press to Scann" Clicked="OnScanButtonClicked" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="Medium" Text="Destination Scan" Margin="15"/>
        <Entry Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  FontSize="Medium"  IsReadOnly="true"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"  FontSize="Medium" Text="Item Scans" Margin="15"/>
        <ListView Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

the image shows e result...

[Android image showing half panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2evE.png)